# How to use youtube upload date as a time comparison to real date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I have this string given to me by youtube rss data and I can grab it and store it, but I dont know how to manipulate the string into something that I am trying to use it for.

```
2012-08-08T16:49:52.000Z
```

I want to use the string above and create a jquery function that will parse it and spit out how long ago the video was uploaded. ex: 1 day ago, 15 days ago, 20 days ago. I dont expect the parsing to be too much work, but if the logic behind figuring out how many days ago a video was uploaded is very hard, then I will just display the upload date as month day. ex: Aug 8

In short:

- I need to grab the date before the T character in the provided string
- Then display it as 3 days ago format or month day format

I do not know how to do either of these. Hopefully someone can help me. :)

UPDATE: So I have grabbed and seperated the date from the rest of the upload information thanks to a comment in this post.

```
var uploadDate = x.substring(0, x.indexOf('T'));
```

giving me `2012-08-08`

UPDATE 2: I have parsed out the month and day with `split()`

```
var date = uploadDate.split('-');
var month = date[1];
var day = date[2];
```

MY CODE after the ANSWER was given

```
function differenceDate(dateStr) {
    var dateString = dateStr.split('T')[0];
    var date = dateString.split('-');
    var firstDate = new Date(parseInt(date[0],10), parseInt(date[1],10)-1, parseInt(date[2],10));
    var secondDate = new Date();
    var diffDate = secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime();
    var converted = diffDate/1000/60/60/24;

    var uploaded;
    if(converted < 1){
        uploaded = 'few hours ago';
    } else if(converted>1 && converted<2){
        uploaded = '1 day ago';
    } else if(converted>2){
        var daysAgo = Math.floor(converted);
        uploaded = daysAgo+ ' days ago';
    }

    return uploaded;
}
var daysAgo = differenceDate( '2012-08-08T16:49:52.000Z' );
```

Comment: `var x = yourRssValueHere;
x = x.substring(0, x.indexOf('T'));
document.write(x);`

That should get you started for removing things before the T.

Comment: @Kwon any idea on how to go about getting the results to end up as '5 days ago', '1 day ago'? I have updated my orig question

Comment: There's probably several ways to output your date's shorthand to a string Javascript can recognize, but in essence, you're going to want to parse your dates (one being the current date, obviously; you can google how to grab the current date with javascript) and then subtract. Something like `var current =  Math.floor(( Date.parse(currentDateHere) - Date.parse(ytUploadDateHere) ) / 86400000);` and then divide `current` by 1000/60/60/24 and then `round()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can grab the date string, i assume you can split it from 'T' char and send index 0 of result array to your favorite date difference function :) i.e.

```
function millisBetween(dateStr) {

    var dateArray = dateStr.split("-");

    // new Date(year, month, day)
    var firstDate = new Date(parseInt(dateArray[0],10), parseInt(dateArray[1],10) - 1, parseInt(dateArray[2],10));

     // today
    var secondDate = new Date();

    var millisBetween = secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime();

    return millisBetween;
}

var strDatePart = "2012-08-08T16:49:52.000Z".split("T")[0];
var millis = millisBetween(strDatePart); // date difference in milliseconds
```

After this, all you have to do is check the millis variable and find out if the video was uploaded just minutes ago, some hours ago or maybe years ago.

Comment: Let me try this out, but it will only ever be "days ago" because I upload every day or other day to my channel. brb with my results

Comment: What am i supposed to get back as a result because i got a large negative number back :/

Comment: OH it returns a milliSECOND difference. makes sense now what the number is. I will try to convert it now

Comment: for whatever reason this line 'var firstDate = new Date(parseInt(date[0],10), parseInt(date[1],10), parseInt(date[2],10));' is returning sept 8 as opposed to aug 8.. I dont know how to fix it. @frkn

Comment: I checked the input right before that line and it shows august 8 but after the offending line it outputs sept 8

Comment: Or i can just subtract 1 from the month array value as a temporary fix.

Comment: It is actually a constant fix as far as i know. I guess JS starts counting the months from 0.

Comment: thanks this was a ton of help! :D got it all working with conversions and all the if statements! <3